# Neo4 Movie Sample Application - Autogenerated files?

Tags: java, neo4j

This question is about the Neo4J sample webapp for their Movie database:

https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-java-spring-data-neo4j-4

Are the Movie.java, Person.java, and Role.java files autogenerated?  They look like they might be but I am  not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are asking, but those files are not autogenerated.